# Is there equivalence of iPhone Webkit Api on Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there something which can allow to embed webapp in windows phone 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation for the [Windows Phone Webbrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431812%28VS.92%29.aspx).  You can navigate it and sink events [easily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431807%28VS.92%29.aspx).  Basically it's a port of MSHTML from the desktop version of IE.  Probably IE7 or IE8.

```
<phone:WebBrowser Source="http://www.bing.com" />
```

**Speculation Follows**

I wouldn't expect to see a WebKit based browser until someone gets around to it, and even then just using the built-in browser will be much easier as an app developer (maybe not as a web developer).

Microsoft certainly won't be porting it.  Mozilla guys may port Gecko.  I'm sure Opera will try to get their stuff on it.  But I don't see Apple bringing webkit to it.  Maybe Google... ?

**End Speculation**

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone 7 has a WebBrowser control which you can embed on our pages and control programmatically.